# Integrating adb in a web page

Tags: html, adb

I am trying to use adb features from the web without installing anything locally.

For eg. Just like app.webadb.com
Works.

Any help would be appreciated

I even researched a lot on this topic that how is webadb working and found no clue of that.

Comment: [Access USB Devices on the Web](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/usb/)

Comment: That is no issue but how will I run adb commands on that device???

Comment: You won't be able to run ADB itself. Instead, you'd use the underlying USB protocol to send commands. ADB is open source. Maybe you can start [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/modules/adb/README.md).

Comment: Looks like there's a WebADB implementation over [here](https://yume-chan.github.io/ya-webadb/) and an article about how to use it over [here](https://www.thecustomdroid.com/webadb-run-adb-from-web-browser/.)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.